# How to get Total Length or Count on Two Different Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I know the question is hard to understand so I will explain how I want it to be **I have this array of data:**

```
const products = [
  {
    name: "Product A",
    reviews: [
      {
        comment: "Good Product",
        username: "Alif",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Product B",
    reviews: [
      {
        comment: "Bad Product",
        username: "Alif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Good Product",
        username: "Atif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Ok Product",
        username: "Esha",
      },
    ],
  },
];


products.map(({ reviews }) => {
  console.log(reviews.length);
});
```

I would like to get the length of the reviews but since both objects are separate which is the Product A and the Product B, **I get separated length or count like this:**

[image]

**I would please like the result to be total length of 4 or count of 4**, so I thought of merging the array. Are there any other methods to be done?

Comment: `products.flatMap(({ reviews }) => reviews).length`?

Comment: Thanks for answering, ok will give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A naive solution could be:

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Product A",
    reviews: [{
      comment: "Good Product",
      username: "Alif",
    }, ],
  },
  {
    name: "Product B",
    reviews: [{
        comment: "Bad Product",
        username: "Alif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Good Product",
        username: "Atif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Ok Product",
        username: "Esha",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const allProducts = products.flatMap(({
  reviews
}) => reviews);

console.log(allProducts.length);
```

This maps over each product and extracts the reviews arrays, which are then flattened into a single array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will put this as the solution hasnt been 11 minutes yet, thanks againn

Comment: Havent heard of flatMap before learned something new that will help with my project

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a [reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const totalAmountOfReviews = products.reduce((commentCount, product) => {
  return commentCount + product.reviews.length;
}, 0);

console.log(totalAmountOfReviews); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks for answering gives me the same result too, I will try also this for my project

Answer (score 2):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the total of reviews

```
products.reduce((acc, { reviews }) => acc + reviews.length, 0);
```

```js
const products = [
  {
    name: "Product A",
    reviews: [
      {
        comment: "Good Product",
        username: "Alif",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Product B",
    reviews: [
      {
        comment: "Bad Product",
        username: "Alif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Good Product",
        username: "Atif",
      },
      {
        comment: "Ok Product",
        username: "Esha",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = products.reduce((acc, { reviews }) => acc + reviews.length, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering gives me the same result, I will try also this for my project